# Arcgis Server name include domain

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

When I create a web app using the template it points to `cos-t420:8399/arcgisoutput` but I need it to be `cos-t420.web.com.sg:8399/arcgisoutput`
How can it be done? am using the java version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Adrian and Welcome to GIS-SE.

I have not tested this and dont have a v10 Java edition handy.  However, I believe the following should work, but please try it on a development environment first.

**The first thing I would check before implementing the below, is that you cannot change the arcgisserver cache folder through the Manager GUI or ArcCatalog server properties.**

If you cannot find a way to do it via ArcCatalog/Manager, try the following:

1. Stop the SOM.
2. Open the Server.dat file
3. Look for the ServerDirectories tag and make the following change:

[image]

4, Start SOM

*Further Reference*
[Source is from v10 Help.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_java_help/index.html#//00920000009r000000)
[Diagnostics error for arcgisserver folders for Linux/Solaris](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_java_help/index.html#//0092000012w5000000)